# Keeping .isPlaying() on True while muting sound via setVolume(0,0)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, volume, mute

I encountered unexpected issue while working with audio mute functions on my app. I have multiple conditions set on status of isPlaying()==true but when players mute the app (mysound.setVolume(0,0), my app acts as isPlaying()==False, thus all of my if conditions stop working. With .setVolume(0,0) I expected my MediaPlayer to be still running in the background only with no sound -> still triggering my conditions on isPlaying()==True.

Do you guys please have some advise how I could implement this? I tried setting volume to its bare minimum  (0.001f, 0.001f) to trick this but it acted as isPlaying()==False again.

I also tried (0.01f, 0.01f), this resulted in full volume sound which was also unwanted.

Here is sample of my condition linked to isPlaying()==True :

```
@Override
    public void update() {

        if (Score.getScore() <= 7 ) {
            xPosition-=speed+0.3;
            separation= separation-0.15;

        }else if(GameManager.getMpMotivationBuildup1().isPlaying()==true){      
            xPosition-=speed+0.35;
            separation= separation-0.40;
        }

}
```

Sample code for mute on click:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.image_button_android:


        if(getGameState()==GameState.GAME_OVER) {


            GameManager.gameState=GameState.INITIAL;
            Random rand=new Random();
            int[] images={
             R.drawable.motivation1,R.drawable.motivation2,R.drawable.motivation3
            ,R.drawable.motivation4,R.drawable.motivation5,R.drawable.motivation6
            ,R.drawable.motivation7,R.drawable.motivation8,R.drawable.motivation9
            ,R.drawable.motivation10,R.drawable.motivation11,R.drawable.motivation12
            ,R.drawable.motivation13,R.drawable.motivation14,R.drawable.motivation15
            ,R.drawable.motivation16,R.drawable.motivation17,R.drawable.motivation18
            ,R.drawable.motivation19,R.drawable.motivation20,R.drawable.motivation21
            ,R.drawable.motivation22,R.drawable.motivation23,R.drawable.motivation24
            ,R.drawable.motivation25,R.drawable.motivation26,R.drawable.motivation27
            ,R.drawable.motivation28,R.drawable.motivation29,R.drawable.motivation30

            };

            MainActivity.motivateme.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);   

                    }else {

                    }

                break;

            case R.id.rate_button:
                MainActivity.getInstance().rateUs((android.view.View) View);

                break;

            case R.id.volume_on:

                    //MainActivity.vibe.vibrate(80);

                    MainActivity.VolumeOn.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    MainActivity.VolumeOff.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                    paused=true;

                //Muting sound
                GameManager.getMpPoint().setVolume(0,0);
                GameManager.getMpSwoosh().setVolume(0,0);
                GameManager.getMpDie().setVolume(0,0);
                GameManager.getMpHit().setVolume(0,0);
                GameManager.getMpWing().setVolume(0f,0f);
                GameManager.getMpMetal().setVolume(0f,0f);


                GameManager.getMpCutePiano().setVolume(0,0f);
                GameManager.getMpWildWest().setVolume(0f,0f);


                GameManager.getMpMotivationBuildup1().setVolume(0f,0f);

                GameManager.getMpMotivationBuildup2().setVolume(0f,0f);
                GameManager.getMpMotivationBuildup3().setVolume(0f,0f);
                
                break;

            case R.id.volume_off:

              
                MainActivity.VolumeOn.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                MainActivity.VolumeOff.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                paused=false;

                //Enabling sound
                GameManager.getMpPoint().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpSwoosh().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpDie().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpHit().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpWing().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpWing().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpMetal().setVolume(1,1);


                GameManager.getMpCutePiano().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpWildWest().setVolume(1,1);


                GameManager.getMpMotivationBuildup1().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpMotivationBuildup2().setVolume(1,1);
                GameManager.getMpMotivationBuildup3().setVolume(1,1);


                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
```

Sample code of sounds initialization:

```
 public void update() {


        switch (gameState) {


            case PLAYING:

                bird.update();
                obstacleManager.update();  //updating of pipes not needed in gameover


                if(Score.getScore()==7){

                    mpMotivationBuildup1.start();


                }

                if((Score.getScore()==25) && (mpMotivationBuildup1.isPlaying()==false)){

                    // mpMetal.reset();
                    //mpMetal.prepare();
                    mpWildWest.start();


                }


                if((Score.getScore()==40) && mpWildWest.isPlaying()==false){
                    mpMotivationBuildup2.start();

                }

                if((Score.getScore()==60) && (mpMotivationBuildup2.isPlaying()==false)){
                    mpMetal.start();
                }



                if((Score.getScore()==80) && mpMetal.isPlaying()==false){
                    mpCutePiano.start();

                }

                if((Score.getScore()==100)&& mpMetal.isPlaying()==false){
                    mpMotivationBuildup3.start();
                }

                if((Score.getScore()==130) && mpMotivationBuildup2.isPlaying()==false){
                    mpMetal.start();
                }

                updateButtons();
                break;

            case GAME_OVER:
                bird.update();  

                mpCutePiano.stop();
                mpWildWest.stop();
                mpMetal.stop();//stops metal on game over


                mpMotivationBuildup1.stop();
                mpMotivationBuildup2.stop();
                mpMotivationBuildup3.stop();



                updateButtons();
                break;


            case INITIAL:

                initGame(); 



                if(GameOverButtonsTouch.isPaused()==false) {
                    mpMetal=MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.metal);
                    mpCutePiano=MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.cutepiano);
                    mpWildWest=MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.wildwest);

                    mpMotivationBuildup1=MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.mbuildp1);
                    mpMotivationBuildup2=MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.mbuildp2);
                    mpMotivationBuildup3=MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.mbuildp3);

                }else {

                }
                updateButtons();
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much for any help provided!

Comment: Please provide a code sample. It is nearly impossible to help when we do not know what is going wrong.

Comment: I am sorry, now it is added.

Comment: Please trim down to remove irrelevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the issue by replacing ".setVolume(0,0)" logic with:

```
 AudioManager   mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int current_volume =mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      
        int set_volume=0;
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,set_volume, 0);
```

This keeps the state of .isPlaying()==True unchanged while muting the volume as expected.